# What does the A Missing Page trinket do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

In the Binding of Isaac expansion I found a trinket called A Missing Page, and so far I have not noticed any effect. What does this trinket do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Trinkets are available in Wrath of the Lamb?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71059/which-trinkets-are-available-in-wrath-of-the-lamb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A Missing Page - Random book effect when player uses their Space item.
>   Chance of activating the Necronomicon when taking damage.

Source: http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Trinket